# Merge 2 vectors on equal time values

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have collected two types of data. One is a struct `Outputs` with 3 fields: `Outputs.time`, `Outputs.signals` and an unimportant one. `Outputs.time` is a columnvector containing all the time values (where the data is sampled), `Outputs.signals` has 15 rows, on each row the values and properties of a signal (so there are 15 signals in total). Consequently `Outputs.signals(i).values` has the same number of rows as `Outputs.time`.

Now i have another table with 4 columns: `LabData.time`, `LabData.NdBoiler`, `LabData.NdOutput` and an unimportant one. `Outputs.time` contains all the computer sampled data, `LabData.time` only some measurements taken by hand. Ergo, `Outputs.time` is way larger than `LabData.time`, but at certain times (where `Outputs.time` = `LabData.time`) there are values for both `Outputs.signals` and the other columns of `LabData`.

The goal is to put the values of `LabData.NdBoiler` and `LabData.NdOutput` in `Outputs.signals(16)` and `Outputs.signals(17)` for the time-samples where the value is known. For the other values, `Outputs.signals(16) = NaN` and `Outputs.signals(17) = NaN`. But i dont know how to do that, could you help me?

Example:

```
Outputs.time = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];
Outputs.signals(1).values = [1111; 2222; 3333; 4444; 5555]; %and so on for the other signals

LabData.time = [2; 4];
LabData.NdBoiler = [1.23; 1.32];
%% Now the final result should be
Outputs.signals(16).values = [NaN; 1.23; NaN; 1.32; NaN]
```

Comment: You could perhaps make a small example to illustrate your problem?

Comment: You're right, i have added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to first create the vector of `NaN`s whereafter you match the timepoints using [`ismember`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to substitute the values you know in.

```
Outputs.signals(16).values = nan(1,length(Outputs.time)); %Vector of nans
Lia = ismember(Outputs.time,LabData.time); %Where does the times match?
Outputs.signals(16).values(Lia) = LabData.NdBoiler; %substitute
```